# wp_list_categories depending of a selected tag

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-list-categories

I would like to display a list of categories with the current count of posts in each category depending of a selected tag.

For example if the tag A (2 posts tagged) is selected the categories list would be:

```
- cat A (2)
-- cat Aa (1)
-- cat Ab (1)
```

And if the tag B (3 posts tagged) is selected:

```
- cat A (3)
-- cat Aa (1)
-- cat Ab (1)
-- cat Ac (1)
```

As there is no possibility to specify a tag in the arguments of `wp_list_categories`, did you have ideas about how to process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of arguments which wp_list_categories function could be applied to. One of them is show count which is a boolean 0 -> false, 1 -> true. Check the child_of parameter too.

```
$args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'style'              => 'list',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'hide_empty'         => 1,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'feed'               => '',
    'feed_type'          => '',
    'feed_image'         => '',
    'exclude'            => '',
    'exclude_tree'       => '',
    'include'            => '',
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
    'show_option_none'   => __( '' ),
    'number'             => null,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => 0,
    'current_category'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'         => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'walker'             => null
);
wp_list_categories( $args );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: thanks for your help, I’m aware about the bunch of arguments in `wp_list_categories`, the problem is to combine these args with a specific post tag.

Answer (score 1):

With the use of wp_list_categories, it is not possible to combine with post tag. So first filter posts based on tag id and then based on those posts ids, find categories like shown in below code :

```
<h2><?php _e('Categories by Tags'); ?></h2>
<form action="" method="post">
      <?php wp_dropdown_categories('taxonomy=post_tag&show_option_none=Select tag&orderby=name&name=posttag&selected='.$_POST['posttag']); ?>
      <input name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="View" />
</form>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag_id' => $_POST['posttag'] ) );
    $categories = array();

     // The Loop
     if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                $post_cat = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category');

                foreach ($post_cat as $key => $value)
                {
                    if($value->parent==0)
                    {
                        $categories[$value->term_id]['main_category']=$value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $categories[$value->parent]['sub_categories'][$value->term_id]=$value;
                    }

                }
        }

        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($categories as $cat_key => $cat_value)
        {
             foreach ($cat_value as $c_key => $c_value)
             {
                    if($c_key == "main_category")
                    {
                        echo "<li>".$c_value->name." (".$c_value->count.")";
                    }
                    if($c_key == "sub_categories")
                    {
                        echo "<ul>";
                        foreach ($c_value as $sc_key => $sc_value)
                        {
                            echo "<li>".$sc_value->name." (".$sc_value->count.")</li>";
                        }
                        echo "</ul></li>";
                    }

             }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    } else {
         // no posts found
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: Look good, I'll have a try in a moment, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<?php
$termID = 25; //Need cat ID
$termName = 'category'; // Need tax name
$catMain = get_term_by( 'id', $termID, $termName );
$termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $termName);

if (is_array($termchildren) ) {
    $return.='<ul>';
    $return.='<li>'.$catMain->name.'('.$catMain->count.')</li>';
    $return .='<ul>';
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
        $childTerm = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $termName );
        $return .='<li>'.$childTerm->name.'('.$childTerm->count.')</li>';
    }
    $return .= '</ul></ul>';

}
echo $return;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your help @cody but it look not possible to specify a tag